# Category for student and education

Tags: category

The term `student` tends to creep into the category `job` but being in education is not a job as you aren't paid for it.

---

- banker
- police officer
- nurse

are all positions in `work` under the category `jobs`

like

- undergranduate
- postgraduate
- pupil
- apprentice
- student

  are all positions in `education`

but what category are they under?

Comment: Wouldn't Banker, Police Officer, and Nurse just be under the category of jobs?

Comment: In 'Crystal' clear English, *job* is one syllable and *occupation* is four; so although *job* is less appropriate it will be preferred when describing any serious activity..

Comment: I think I'd name my categories 'work' and 'education', then the related subgroups, 'jobs' and 'courses'. Banker, police officer and nurse are positions (or types of job) within the overall category of 'work'. Postgraduate, undergraduate, higher education, schooling and apprenticeship (when attached to a centre of learning) are all positions (or types of student course) within the overall category of education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understand your question:

```
/work/jobs/banker
/work/jobs/police officer
/work/jobs/nurse
/education/???/undergraduate
/education/???/postgraduate
/education/???/pupil
/education/???/apprentice
/education/???/student
```

Q1: Why do we need the `???` category at all? Why not have:

```
/education/undergraduate
/education/postgraduate
/education/pupil
/education/apprentice
/education/student
```

Keep in mind that `job` is a very generic word in English, it does not *merely* mean "a paid position of regular employment" (Google), it also means:

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/job): anything a person is expected or obliged to do; duty; responsibility:

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/job): a specific duty, role, or function

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/job_2): your duty in a particular situation or organization

So the question "what is your job" can be legitimately answered with "I am a student".

However, in your specific context, I have no idea what you're trying to distinguish "student" from.

Comment: As Julie said `work/jobs/`, `education/course` works quite nicely. I wanted to know if there was a word that existed that I wasn't aware of as it seemed there should be.